# Postfix do not accept emails from gmail

Tags: postfix

Using Dovecot/postif last release on Debian Wheezy
Mails from gmail are not accepted.

log:

```
Sep 10 14:38:30 ns2281425 postfix/smtpd[27084]: warning: cannot get RSA certificate from file /etc/postfix/smtpd.crt: disabling TLS support
Sep 10 14:38:30 ns2281425 postfix/smtpd[27084]: warning: TLS library problem: 27084:error:02001002:system library:fopen:No such file or directory:bss_file.c:398:fopen('/etc/postfix/smtpd.crt','r'):
Sep 10 14:38:30 ns2281425 postfix/smtpd[27084]: warning: TLS library problem: 27084:error:20074002:BIO routines:FILE_CTRL:system lib:bss_file.c:400:
Sep 10 14:38:30 ns2281425 postfix/smtpd[27084]: warning: TLS library problem: 27084:error:140DC002:SSL routines:SSL_CTX_use_certificate_chain_file:system lib:ssl_rsa.c:722:
Sep 10 14:38:30 ns2281425 postfix/smtpd[27084]: connect from mail-qe0-f47.google.com[209.85.128.47]
Sep 10 14:38:31 ns2281425 postfix/cleanup[27089]: 40F2AC0CAC: message-id=<20130910123831.40F2AC0CAC@ns2281425.ovh.net>
Sep 10 14:38:31 ns2281425 postfix/smtpd[27084]: disconnect from mail-qe0-f47.google.com[209.85.128.47]
Sep 10 14:38:31 ns2281425 postfix/qmgr[25342]: 40F2AC0CAC: from=<double-bounce@ns2281425.ovh.net>, size=900, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Sep 10 14:38:31 ns2281425 postfix/local[27091]: warning: required alias not found: postmaster
Sep 10 14:38:31 ns2281425 postfix/local[27091]: 40F2AC0CAC: to=<postmaster@ns2281425.ovh.net>, orig_to=<postmaster>, relay=local, delay=0.01, delays=0.01/0/0/0, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (discarded)
Sep 10 14:38:31 ns2281425 postfix/qmgr[25342]: 40F2AC0CAC: removed
```

Postfix conf:

```
# See /usr/share/postfix/main.cf.dist for a commented, more complete version


# Debian specific:  Specifying a file name will cause the first
# line of that file to be used as the name.  The Debian default
# is /etc/mailname.
#myorigin = /etc/mailname

smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Debian/GNU)
biff = no

# appending .domain is the MUA's job.
append_dot_mydomain = no

# Uncomment the next line to generate "delayed mail" warnings
#delay_warning_time = 4h

readme_directory = no

# TLS parameters
smtpd_tls_cert_file=/etc/postfix/smtpd.crt
smtpd_tls_key_file=/etc/postfix/smtpd.key
smtp_tls_CAfile = /etc/postfix/cakey.pem
smtpd_use_tls=yes
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache
smtp_sasl_password_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/relay_passwd

smtpd_sasl_type = dovecot
smtpd_sasl_path = private/auth
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, permit_sasl_authenticated, reject_unauth_destination
smtpd_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
smtpd_sasl_local_domain = domain.lan

# See /usr/share/doc/postfix/TLS_README.gz in the postfix-doc package for
# information on enabling SSL in the smtp client.

myhostname = ns2281425.ovh.net
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
myorigin = /etc/mailname
mydestination = ns2281425.ovh.net, localhost.ovh.net, , localhost
#relayhost = [smtp.mailoo.org]:225
relayhost =
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8, 5.39.72.228
mailbox_size_limit = 0
recipient_delimiter = +
#inet_interfaces = 127.0.0.1, 5.39.72.228
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = ipv4
mailbox_command = /usr/lib/dovecot/deliver
home_mailbox = Maildir/

virtual_transport = dovecot
dovecot_destination_recipient_limit = 1

# Wait until the RCPT TO command before evaluating restrictions
smtpd_delay_reject = yes

# Basics Restrictions
smtpd_helo_required = yes
strict_rfc821_envelopes = yes

# Requirements for the connecting server
smtpd_client_restrictions =
    permit_mynetworks,
    permit_sasl_authenticated,
    reject_rbl_client bl.spamcop.net,
    reject_rbl_client dnsbl.njabl.org,
    reject_rbl_client cbl.abuseat.org,
    reject_rbl_client sbl-xbl.spamhaus.org,
    reject_rbl_client list.dsbl.org,
    permit

# Requirements for the HELO statement
smtpd_helo_restrictions =
    permit_mynetworks,
    permit_sasl_authenticated,
    reject_non_fqdn_hostname,
    reject_invalid_hostname,
    permit

# Requirements for the sender address
smtpd_sender_restrictions =
    permit_mynetworks,
    permit_sasl_authenticated,
    reject_non_fqdn_sender,
    reject_unknown_sender_domain,
    permit

# Requirement for the recipient address
smtpd_recipient_restrictions =
    permit_mynetworks,
    permit_sasl_authenticated,
    reject_non_fqdn_recipient,
    reject_unknown_recipient_domain,
    reject_unauth_destination,
    permit

virtual_alias_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual
```

Any idea please?

Now mails are coming from gmail. But logs are:

```
Sep 10 15:17:02 ns2281425 postfix/smtpd[1720]: warning: 49.128.85.209.dnsbl.njabl.org: RBL lookup error: Host or domain name not found. Name service error for name=49.128.85.209.dnsbl.njabl.org type=A: Host not found, try again
Sep 10 15:17:17 ns2281425 postfix/smtpd[1720]: warning: 49.128.85.209.list.dsbl.org: RBL lookup error: Host or domain name not found. Name service error for name=49.128.85.209.list.dsbl.org type=A: Host not found, try again
Sep 10 15:17:17 ns2281425 postfix/cleanup[1770]: warning: database /etc/postfix/virtual.db is older than source file /etc/postfix/virtual
Sep 10 15:17:17 ns2281425 postfix/smtpd[1720]: 1449DC0C96: client=mail-qe0-f49.google.com[209.85.128.49]
Sep 10 15:17:17 ns2281425 postfix/cleanup[1770]: 1449DC0C96: message-id=<CAOen1CZ90Jpgg7pfbH0zTyX9QvcrAXS3Ts=OiQdYmrdH4EzZjg@mail.gmail.com>
Sep 10 15:17:17 ns2281425 postfix/qmgr[921]: 1449DC0C96: from=<xxxxxxx@gmail.com>, size=1942, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Sep 10 15:17:17 ns2281425 postfix/smtpd[1720]: disconnect from mail-qe0-f49.google.com[209.85.128.49]
Sep 10 15:17:17 ns2281425 postfix/local[1771]: 1449DC0C96: to=<test.ue-lands@ns2281425.ovh.net>, orig_to=<test@ue-lands.com>, relay=local, delay=31, delays=30/0/0/0.13, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (delivered to command: /usr/lib/dovecot/deliver)
Sep 10 15:17:17 ns2281425 postfix/qmgr[921]: 1449DC0C96: removed
```

Comment: Your logs do not indicate a problem.  What exactly is it that leads you to think something is the matter?  You accepted the message, it got queued as 1449DC0C96, and then disposed of by the queue, which usually indicates delivery to something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first two lines of the log are clear:

```
warning: cannot get RSA certificate from file /etc/postfix/smtpd.crt: disabling TLS support
warning: TLS library problem: 27084:error:02001002:system library:fopen:No such file or directory:bss_file.c:398:fopen('/etc/postfix/smtpd.crt','r'):
```

The configured certificate can't be found and postfix disables TLS Support, but it seems Google only delivers mail only over secured connections.

Comment: Ok, changed are ok for ssl, it works, but some error messages in logs (see my edited question). Thanks

Comment: Found the last errors on logs and corrected! Thanks